# node-canvas: Using custom font

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

I would like to know how to use custom font with node-canvas.

Here is my attempt but it does not work so far:

```
var Canvas = require('canvas')
    , Image = Canvas.Image
    , Font = Canvas.Font
    , path = require('path');

var gubblebum = new Font('gubblebum', fontFile('GUBBLO___.ttf'));

function fontFile(name) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '../fonts', name);
}

function draw() {
  var canvas = new Canvas(100, 100)
    , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.addFont(gubblebum);
  ctx.font = 'bold 40 gubblebum';
  ctx.fillText('test', 25, 45);

  return canvas;
}

module.exports = draw;
```

When rendered in a browser, the font is left unchanged from the default, as well as the size.

The font file is correctly loaded. Otherwise, an exception would be thrown.

Interestingly, when I do ctx.font = 'bold 40 someGibberish'; the font size is applied correctly.

Comment: It seems right now that fonts on node-canvas are broken, it looks like you need to disable pango, but I'm still trying to figure out how to do that and rebuild for the module

Answer (score 9):

This should now "Just Work" in node-canvas 2.0+. See the new `Canvas.registerFont` method: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/#registerfont.

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up getting node canvas to work with custom fonts.

First I used an older version of Cairo.  I used Brew to install all of the dependencies, since it told me which ones I had and which ones were linked correctly, and then once all the dependencies were working correctly, I uninstalled the Cairo version from Brew and installed version 1.12.X (patch version 18 I think it was) of Cairo.  This solved a Mac OSX Issue with the font size, but I couldn't load in fonts.

So after some investigation I found there was also an issue with the latest Node Canvas module, so I hard set the version to 1.1.0 in my package.json and FINALLY I got custom fonts to load and size correctly.

**So TL;DR**:  Use Cairo version 1.12.X and Node Canvas 1.1.0 and it should work I think?  It took me a while to get it working.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on setting this up? Did you clone and compile a Cairo 1.12.X from source? Or did you somehow install an older version via brew?

So far I've cloned and built the 1.12.X version from source, but trying to run `npm install canvas` yields more errors, even when setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the src folder where cairo was compiled.

Comment: I had to find it via the source.  I went and grabbed the tarball and installed it manually and then replaced the brew version with that and then linked it to the correct required packages.  IIRC.  It's been a while and I swapped from using node-canvas (because it's a pain) to using node-gd which works better.